# minecraft java edition 1.13 player join detector?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a game that uses commands in such a way that players disconnecting then reconnecting could break the commands. I was wondering if there is a way to detect when players join the game in 1.13.2 and run a command to give them an item. When I researched this, I found solutions for older versions using /testfor or stat.leaveGame, but those seem to be outdated in 1.13. If someone could show me the commands to use as well as the layout for command blocks/redstone that would be great. It can be for the second time they join only, or for all times that they do. Thanks

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange should not be re-asked just because the current answers are outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you're looking for that involved `testfor` and `stat.leavegame` would now be best suited by using `execute` and `minecraft.custom:minecraft.leave_game`. essentially, you would do all the same things you would with `testfor`, **except no redstone is needed now.** when you use `execute`, you can tell the game to run it if they have a leave game score of 0 (or whatever you need to do for it) by doing something like below;

```
/execute at @a as @s if score @s <scoreName> matches 0 run <command>
```

you could also do a different one, with this technique, for a command you want to run if their leave game score is a certain about (or higher than a certain amount);

```
/execute at @a as @s if score @s <scoreName> matches <value> run <command>
```

for `<value>`, **to make it run for everything up to that value or everything that value and greater, use `..<value>` or `<value>..`, respectively.**

Comment: Thanks! this was extremely helpful!

Comment: no problem! if you need anything else, don't be afraid to ask :D